# How to open file from Finder with Mac-Catalyst App

Tags: swift, file-association, mac-catalyst

I am looking for way to receive opened file's URL from Finder of macOS.
I implemented ZIP document type association into info.plist of an Mac-Catalyst app. So If user once associated ZIP file to my app for default app, user can double click ZIP file and launch my app.

But currently my app can't receive that opened file URL because I don't know which place/delegate function is good to receive that URL.
I believe I should implement that delegate function in SceneDelegate or AppDelegate, and I should also implement launch first viewcontroller with Storyboard manually.
This app window launching chain (that is from file double-click, to end of call viewcontroller) is very difficult for me.

Is there any help document or sample code?
Thank you.

Comment: Hey! did you ever figure this out? I would love to open some files directly from my Catalyst app.